# Have a div stretch across the window browser

Tags: css, html

I have a div which I want to stretch the whole screen. It does with a 100% width but when the browser size is changed, shrunk in size, it only does 100% of that size. I the changed it to 1000 px, but on my desktop it doesn't stretch.

Basically I want a div similar to the one Google has at the top of its homepage. Where, if the window is shrunk, it doesn't change at all and is stretched 100% on every single desktop/ laptop resolution

Comment: `width: 100%;` should work. Please post a jsFiddle or screenshot showing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `min-width` to stretch the `<div>` for the bigger screens and not go under 1000px on smaller ones:

```
div {
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google has is a minimum width defined on its header:

```
header {
    /* width: auto; possible to omit since it's the default value*/
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/E78WE/

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
.thisStyle { min-width: 1000px; position:absolute; z-index: 9999; width:100%; height:20px; top: 0; left: 0; color: #ffffff;}
```

and add a div to the body:

```
<div class="thisStyle">this is some content</div>
```

and style it the way you want it to look (background color, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how google does it :)

min-width: 980px;
position: absolute;
width: 1663px;